# Updating an open .txt file in python

Tags: python, text

I want to run a script in the background which would print useful information that I would need to see every ~5min. I thought I could write text into text file while having notepad open, so I could see live updates. Is that possible to do?

Is there an alternative solution?

Comment: Why not just `print` to `stdout` and write it to the file for more permanent storage separately?

Comment: Not easily. You can't "insert" text into a file, only overwrite bytes starting at a given location and append to the end of the file. Text editors exist to abstract away the details of shifting bytes to make room for additional bytes like you want. Unless the text editor provides an API you can use to do what you want, you'll basically have to implement the text-editor features yourself to edit the file.

Comment: Thanks! As mentioned I need to see live updates rather than store it somewhere.

And thanks chepner, is there an easy alternative to this then?

Answer (score 0):

**Printing**

As @esqew suggested just use `print` or `stdout`. You can even print in color with some super easy libraries [like this one](https://pypi.org/project/colorama/).

Example Code:

```
from time import sleep

for _ in range(10):
    print('I am a noob') # state the obvious
    sleep(5 * 60) # every 5 mins
```

**Writing To File**

You can also write to file. Easy way is to append

Example Code:

```
from time import sleep

for _ in range(10):
    with open("myfile.txt", "w") as file:
        file.write('I am a noob') # state the obvious
    sleep(5 * 60) # every 5 mins
```

Comment: Yes, but the key thing I need is to see text updating as it is open. ie Notepad open in the corner with text lines being added every 5min or so.